# Why do I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined" in my class constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

### Background

I am making a Chrome extension that prints a log once a page reloads. I have all my functions in one bug page, and so lately I decided to make my code readable and refactor it using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

### Problem

I managed to get my extension up and running, but now, every time I load the page, a get a lot of errors.

Namely, I get the error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined` in my cat's constructor!

**init.js**:

```
"use strict";
window.onload = function() {
  let cat = new Cat("Boby");
  console.log(cat.toString());
};
```

**mammal.js**:

```
"use strict";
class Mammal{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.kingdom = "mammalia";
  }
}
```

**cat.js**:

```
"use strict";
class Cat extends Mammal{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = "Cat";
  }

  toString(){
    return this.type + " from kingdom " + this.kingdom + " has name " + this.name;
  }
}
```

At first, I thought I had a problem with my JSON, since each class is in a separate file, perhaps the files were not being loaded in the correct order.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "some tool",
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["myWebsite"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "js": [
      "caseList/init.js",
      "caseList/mammal.js",
      "caseList/cat.js"
    ]
  }]
}
```

However, after much debugging and testing, nothing works!
The only thing that seems to 'work' is if I change `class Cat extends Mammal` to `class Cat`.

But since cats are lovely mammals, I don't want to do that!

### Questions:

1. Do Chrome extensions support ES6?
2. How can I fix this code, while keeping class inheritance and separated files?

Comment: What if you reorder the `js` array?

Comment: I get a set of different errors :(

Comment: Related (but should be closed as a dup of the proposed dup-target here): ["Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined" in class constructor](//stackoverflow.com/q/32516204)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, they do, that's why there is no syntax error.

The only explanation for `this is not defined` in class constructor is that inheritance wasn't performed correctly, i.e. the constructor misses `super` (also explains why `class Cat { ... }` works).

It should be

```
class Cat extends Mammal{
  constructor(name){
    super(name);
    ...
```